# DD-wrt serial messages

Tags: python, serial-port, serial-console, dd-wrt

Since I recently bricked my WDR3600 by accidentally flashing wrong firmware with mdt I had to do some soldering to make serial work.

Since the window to entering bootloader cmd was really short I hooked up RPi to and googled a python script to type `tpl` and enter the bootloader cmd for me.

After that my mind started thinking all the various things I could do with the RPi hooked up to serial port. :)

So my question is, is it possible to somehow write additional messages to routers serial console?
What I want to achieve first is getting a message similar to this:

```
Client 00:00:00:00:00:00 connected to an ESSID:xxx on interface athx.x
```

I would then make a python script to listen for this message and do some things. For example switch light on in my room, when I come home and my phone automatically connects to wireless.